# Has anyone had any luck getting a .NET 6 REST API project to work in an AWS Lambda?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api, aws-lambda

I have a very simple ASP.NET 6.0 Web API application, with a Home controller with one `Get` method returning text:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(new { message = "Hello, World!" });
    }
}
```

I've been able to get ASP.NET projects < 6.0 to work, but with .NET 6 I'm running into issues.  There's no longer a `Startup` class; that functionality moved to the implicit `Program` class.  So in my `LambdaEntryPoint` class (which inherits from `APIGatewayProxyFunction`) I'm using `Program` as the Startup:

```
    protected override void Init(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.UseStartup<Program>();
    }
```

I'm getting an error when manually testing from the AWS console: `Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.ExceptionHandling.LambdaValidationException: Unable to load assembly.`  I believe that my naming is correct: `MyAssembly::MyAssembly.LambdaEntryPoint::FunctionHandlerAsync`

The only thing different about my `Program` class is that I had to add `public partial class Program { }` at the bottom so the unit tests would could find `Program` and run.

My Test event looks like this:

```
{
  "resource": "/Home",
  "path": "/Home",
  "httpMethod": "GET",
  "isBase64Encoded": true
}
```

It is a cut down version of the default `Amazon API Gateway AWS Proxy`

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you don't have a Startup class doesn't mean you can't make one, I made a Startup class for my API in .NET 6 and it works fine

Comment: -Thanks for responding.  When you said "I made a Startup class for my API in .NET 6 and it works fine," do you mean for an API project in general, or in the AWS Lambda context, which is where I was having an issue?

Comment: I mean in the AWS Lambda context

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add a Startup.cs class.
The only thing you have to do if you are working with NET6 is in your Program.cs file you have to add this line of code.

This is if you are using a rest API or API GATEWAY

> builder.Services.AddAWSLambdaHosting(LambdaEventSource.RestApi);

This is if you are using your lambda with a url

> builder.Services.AddAWSLambdaHosting(LambdaEventSource.HttpApi);

..and in aws you just have to change the handler with the name of your project and that's it.
MyAssembly

[See the example here in aws](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0g1aK.png)

Comment: "See the example": A red circle around "MyAssembly" is not an example of what you put as your answer. It's a photo with a circle around "MyAssembly" as the handler...